# How to extract raw html from a Scrapy selector?

Tags: python, scrapy, parsel

I'm extracting js data using response.xpath('//*')re_first() and later converting it to python native data. The problem is extract/re methods don't seem to provide a way to not unquote html i.e.

original html:

```
{my_fields:['O&#39;Connor Park'], }
```

extract output:

```
{my_fields:['O'Connor Park'], }
```

turning this output into json won't work.

What's the easiest way around it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer:**

- Scrapy/Parsel selectors' `.re()` and `.re_first()` methods replace HTML entities (except `&lt;`, `&amp;`)
- instead, use `.extract()` or `.extract_first()` to get raw HTML (or raw JavaScript instructions) and use Python's `re` module  on extracted string

**Long answer:**

Let's look at an example input and various ways of extracting Javascript data from HTML.

Sample HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = {a:['O&#39;Connor Park']}
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using scrapy Selector, which is using the [parsel](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel) library underneath, you have several ways of extracting the Javascript snippet:

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> t = """<html lang="en">
... <body>
... <div>
...     <script type="text/javascript">
...         var i = {a:['O&#39;Connor Park']}
...     </script>
...     
... </div>
... </body>
... </html>
... """
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text=t, type="html")
>>> 
>>> # extracting the <script> element as raw HTML
>>> selector.xpath('//div/script').extract_first()
u'<script type="text/javascript">\n        var i = {a:[\'O&#39;Connor Park\']}\n    </script>'
>>> 
>>> # only getting the text node inside the <script> element
>>> selector.xpath('//div/script/text()').extract_first()
u"\n        var i = {a:['O&#39;Connor Park']}\n    "
>>>
```

Now, Using `.re` (or `.re_first`) you get different result:

```
>>> # I'm using a very simple "catch-all" regex
>>> # you are probably using a regex to extract
>>> # that specific "O'Connor Park" string
>>> selector.xpath('//div/script/text()').re_first('.+')
u"        var i = {a:['O'Connor Park']}"
>>> 
>>> # .re() on the element itself, one needs to handle newlines
>>> selector.xpath('//div/script').re_first('.+')
u'<script type="text/javascript">'    # only first line extracted
>>> import re
>>> selector.xpath('//div/script').re_first(re.compile('.+', re.DOTALL))
u'<script type="text/javascript">\n        var i = {a:[\'O\'Connor Park\']}\n    </script>'
>>>
```

The HTML entity `&#39;` has been replaced by an [apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Unicode). This is due to a [`w3lib.html.replace_entities()`](https://w3lib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.html.remove_entities) call in `.re/re_first` implementation (see `parsel` source code, in [`extract_regex`](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/blob/master/parsel/utils.py#L59) function), which is not used when simply calling `extract()` or `extract_first()`

Comment: Excellent answer! The inconsistency in these related method is made more confusing by Scrapy's documentation. Not only does it not mention html entities, it mentions "Percent encoded content is unquoted." by extract() only. Sort of implying that if anything extract is the one that does more decoding than re().

Answer (score 2):

You can also utilise the same function that is used by the `Selector` class' `extract` method, but with different arguments:

```
from lxml import etree
etree.tostring(selector._root)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since parsel 1.2.0 (2017-05-17) you can pass `replace_entities=False` to both `re` and `re_first` to avoid the default behavior.