# Scrapy Converts &#34; to Quote Character in HTML Response?

Tags: scrapy

I have a Scrapy spider that is fetching a web page (from ESPN as it happens) and then extracting a JSON string from the web page using Selector.re()

```
sel = Selector(response)
j = sel.re(u'window\.espn\.scoreboardData[ \t]*=[ \t]*{.*?};')
```

I then parse the JSON as so:

```
start = j[0].index('{')    
json_data = json.loads(j[0][start:-1])
```

This works fine until the JSON string contains a string with an embedded quote character.  If I look at [the web page](http://scores.espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/scoreboard/_/group/50/date/20061113) with the browser's View Source, I see something like this as part of the JSON string:

```
"shortLinkText":"Georgia Tech and &#34;Fab Three&#34;  beat Jackson State"
```

The embedded quote character has been encoded as the HTML equivalent.  However, in the string I get back within Scrapy, that has been decoded into a quote character:

```
"shortLinkText":"Georgia Tech and "Fab Three" beat Jackson State"
```

This causes the JSON parser to fail for obvious reasons.

Is there any workaround for this situation?  A way to force Scrapy not to decode the HTML character?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887730/how-to-extract-raw-html-from-a-scrapy-selector and https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1704

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointer!  I searched all kinds of variants of my question here and couldn't find anything -- I guess "raw HTML" was the proper magic :-)