# Leave characters like &quot; escaped in Selector output

Tags: python, scrapy, parsel

How to extract raw text with a Scrapy (Parsel) selector? By raw, I mean an escaped piece of text with e.g. `&quot;` not turning into `"`.

Here's how to reproduce:

```
>>> Selector('<p>&quot;</p>').css('p::text').get()
'"'
```

Expected output: `&quot;`

Actual output: `"`

Comment: Why would you want that? That character is just html encoded quote, you are always free to encode it back yourself.

Comment: @Granitosaurus HTML tag content is not always HTML text. For example, `<script>` tag content is JavaScript code. A JavaScript object `{"key": "value &quot;"}` will be changed to `{"key": "value ""}` which raises an error when parsing

Comment: `Selector('<script>&quot;</script>')` gives `<Selector xpath=None data='<html><head><script>&quot;</script></hea'>`, while `Selector('<p>&quot;</p>')` gives `<Selector xpath=None data='<html><body><p>"</p></body></html>'>`. It looks like Parsel is smart about where to replace entities and where not to.

Comment: @Gallaecio thank you for the comment. I will check later if this is the case, but IIRC it was working the same both for `<p>` and `<script>` tags.

Comment: I tested with the latest version, so if that is the case try upgrading first, maybe they introduced this recently.

Comment: May this be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887730/how-to-extract-raw-html-from-a-scrapy-selector?