# Get HTML inside div tag Python Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have this spider in scrapy

```python
import scrapy


class ProductDetailSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'productdetail'
    allowed_domains = ['bisabeli.id']
    start_urls = [
        "https://bisabeli.id/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=7874"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        description = response.css('div.producttab div#tab-description div#collapse-description').get().strip()

        yield {
            'description': description,
        }
```

And when I run this spider in console with

```console
scrapy crawl productdetail
```

The result is:

```json
{
    "description": "<div id=\"co
llapse-description\" class=\"desc-collapse showup\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>Deskripsi Realme X2 Pro 12GB/256GB - Pre Order - Biru</p><p>barang repack</p><p>Apa itu Repack :</p><p>Kartu garansi Konsumen dpt lembar pembeli lalu penjual ambil bagian KG l
embar penjual, utk kami bantu daftarkan klaim warranty nya nanti 1 tahun</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>Garansi resmi 1 tahun</p><p><br></p><p>OS Android</p><p>OS ver Android 9.0 (Pie); ColorOS 6.1</p><p>SIM Nano SIM , Dual SIM , Dual Standby</p><p>CPU
 Qualcomm SDM855 Snapdragon 855+ (7nm)</p><p>Octa-core</p><p>Kecepatan CPU 2.96 GHz (1x2.96 GHz Kryo 485 &amp; 3x2.42 GHz Kryo 485 &amp; 4x1.8 GHz Kryo 485)</p><p>Storage 64GB , 128GB , 256GB</p><p>RAM 8GB , 12GB , 6GB</p><p>External Storage No</p><
p>Battery 4000mAh</p><p>50W SuperVOOC Flash Charge</p><p>Ukuran Layar 6.5 inches</p><p>Resolusi FHD+ 2400 x 1080 pixels at 402 ppi</p><p>Super AMOLED, 90Hz display</p><p>Network Tipe 2G , 3G , 4G (LTE)</p><p>2G GSM: 850/900/1800/1900</p><p>3G WCDMA:
 B1/B2/B4/B5/B6/B8/B19</p><p>4G (LTE) LTE FDD: B1/B2/B3/B4/B5/B7/B8/B12/B17/B18/B19/B20/B26/B28</p><p>TD-LTE: B34/B38/B39/B40/B41</p><p>Speed HSPA 42.2/11.5 Mbps, LTE-A</p><p>Kamera Utama 64MP + 13MP + 8MP + 2MP</p><p>Kamera Depan 16MP</p><p>Fitur W
i-Fi , Hotspot/Tethering , GPS , Bluetooth , Flash , Fingerprint Scanner , NFC , 3.5mm Headphone Jack , Quad Cameras</p><p>Ukuran Dimensi 161 x 75.7 x 8.7 mm</p>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>"}
```

What I want to get is all tags inside `div` tag (`'<div id="collapse-description" class="desc-collapse showup">'....'</div>'`),

How I write the code for it?

**Update**

The result I want is like this:

```json
{
    "description": "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>Deskripsi Realme X2 Pro 12GB/256GB - Pre Order - Biru</p><p>barang repack</p><p>Apa itu Repack :</p><p>Kartu garansi Konsumen dpt lembar pembeli lalu penjual ambil bagian KG l
embar penjual, utk kami bantu daftarkan klaim warranty nya nanti 1 tahun</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>Garansi resmi 1 tahun</p><p><br></p><p>OS Android</p><p>OS ver Android 9.0 (Pie); ColorOS 6.1</p><p>SIM Nano SIM , Dual SIM , Dual Standby</p><p>CPU
 Qualcomm SDM855 Snapdragon 855+ (7nm)</p><p>Octa-core</p><p>Kecepatan CPU 2.96 GHz (1x2.96 GHz Kryo 485 &amp; 3x2.42 GHz Kryo 485 &amp; 4x1.8 GHz Kryo 485)</p><p>Storage 64GB , 128GB , 256GB</p><p>RAM 8GB , 12GB , 6GB</p><p>External Storage No</p><
p>Battery 4000mAh</p><p>50W SuperVOOC Flash Charge</p><p>Ukuran Layar 6.5 inches</p><p>Resolusi FHD+ 2400 x 1080 pixels at 402 ppi</p><p>Super AMOLED, 90Hz display</p><p>Network Tipe 2G , 3G , 4G (LTE)</p><p>2G GSM: 850/900/1800/1900</p><p>3G WCDMA:
 B1/B2/B4/B5/B6/B8/B19</p><p>4G (LTE) LTE FDD: B1/B2/B3/B4/B5/B7/B8/B12/B17/B18/B19/B20/B26/B28</p><p>TD-LTE: B34/B38/B39/B40/B41</p><p>Speed HSPA 42.2/11.5 Mbps, LTE-A</p><p>Kamera Utama 64MP + 13MP + 8MP + 2MP</p><p>Kamera Depan 16MP</p><p>Fitur W
i-Fi , Hotspot/Tethering , GPS , Bluetooth , Flash , Fingerprint Scanner , NFC , 3.5mm Headphone Jack , Quad Cameras</p><p>Ukuran Dimensi 161 x 75.7 x 8.7 mm</p>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"}
```

**Update v2**

Trying some code :

```console
description = response.xpath("//div[@class='producttab']//div[@id='tab-description']//div[@id='collapse-description']").get()
```

Result:

```json
{'description': '<div id="co
llapse-description" class="desc-collapse showup">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>Deskripsi Realme X2 Pro 12GB/256GB - Pre Order - Biru</p><p>barang repack</p><p>Apa itu Repack :</p><p>Kartu garansi Konsumen dpt lembar pembeli lalu penjual ambil bagian KG l
embar penjual, utk kami bantu daftarkan klaim warranty nya nanti 1 tahun</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>Garansi resmi 1 tahun</p><p><br></p><p>OS Android</p><p>OS ver Android 9.0 (Pie); ColorOS 6.1</p><p>SIM Nano SIM , Dual SIM , Dual Standby</p><p>CPU
 Qualcomm SDM855 Snapdragon 855+ (7nm)</p><p>Octa-core</p><p>Kecepatan CPU 2.96 GHz (1x2.96 GHz Kryo 485 &amp; 3x2.42 GHz Kryo 485 &amp; 4x1.8 GHz Kryo 485)</p><p>Storage 64GB , 128GB , 256GB</p><p>RAM 8GB , 12GB , 6GB</p><p>External Storage No</p><
p>Battery 4000mAh</p><p>50W SuperVOOC Flash Charge</p><p>Ukuran Layar 6.5 inches</p><p>Resolusi FHD+ 2400 x 1080 pixels at 402 ppi</p><p>Super AMOLED, 90Hz display</p><p>Network Tipe 2G , 3G , 4G (LTE)</p><p>2G GSM: 850/900/1800/1900</p><p>3G WCDMA:
 B1/B2/B4/B5/B6/B8/B19</p><p>4G (LTE) LTE FDD: B1/B2/B3/B4/B5/B7/B8/B12/B17/B18/B19/B20/B26/B28</p><p>TD-LTE: B34/B38/B39/B40/B41</p><p>Speed HSPA 42.2/11.5 Mbps, LTE-A</p><p>Kamera Utama 64MP + 13MP + 8MP + 2MP</p><p>Kamera Depan 16MP</p><p>Fitur W
i-Fi , Hotspot/Tethering , GPS , Bluetooth , Flash , Fingerprint Scanner , NFC , 3.5mm Headphone Jack , Quad Cameras</p><p>Ukuran Dimensi 161 x 75.7 x 8.7 mm</p>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>'}
```

```console
description = response.xpath("//div[@class='producttab']//div[@id='tab-description']//div[@id='collapse-description']/text()").get()
```

result:

```json
{'description': '\n\t\t\t\t\
t\t\t\t\t\t'}
```

```console
description = response.xpath("//div[@class='producttab']//div[@id='tab-description']//div[@id='collapse-description']//text()").get()
```

result:

```json
{'description': '\n\t\t\t\t\
t\t\t\t\t\t'}
```

Still... Not the result I desired...

Comment: you can use modules like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` for this.

Comment: based on `Scrapy` documentation for [Selector](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) `Scrapy` uses module [Parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which uses `lxml`

Comment: what result do you need? single HTML, list of HTMLs, single string (without tags), list of strings (without tags)? Show it in question (not in comment).

Comment: The result I want is single HTML @furas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OLD VERSION:**

At this moment I found only `.re(".+")` to get all (more or less) as list

```
[opening_tag, item, item, ..., closing_tag]
```

If I skip first and last element and use `"".join()` then I can get inner HTML.

```
# without `get()`
description = response.xpath("//div[@class='producttab']//div[@id='tab-description']//div[@id='collapse-description']")

description = description.re('.+')
description = "".join(description[1:-1]).strip()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Old version works only because there are `\n` in HTML - and it splits HTML into list on `\n`

```
["<opening tag>text", "children", "<closing_tag>"]
```

When there is no `\n` then old version create one string

```
[ "<opening tag> text children <closing_tag>" ]
```

similar to `get()`.

Besides every item has structure

```
 <tag> text children_tags </tag> tail
```

and when `\n` is between `text` and children_tags`then old version skips`text` from final result.

Code which works for me for different HTML is

```
import lxml.html

html = '<body>hello<span>good</span>world</body>'

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

text = tree.text or ''
children = [lxml.html.tostring(x).decode() for x in item.getchildren()]

inner_html = text + "".join(children).strip()

print(inner_html)
```

Result:

```
hello<span>good</span>world
```

It seems `scrapy` already uses `lxml` in [Selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) so `lxml` should be already installed.

---

Minimal working code:

```
import scrapy
import lxml.html

def get_inner_html(html):

    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

    text = tree.text or ''  # to skip `None`
    children = [lxml.html.tostring(x).decode() for x in tree.getchildren()]

    inner_html = text + "".join(children).strip()

    return inner_html 

class ProductDetailSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'productdetail'
    allowed_domains = ['bisabeli.id']
    
    start_urls = [
        "https://bisabeli.id/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=7874"
    ]

        
    def parse(self, response):
        print('--- example 1 ---')
        
        html = response.xpath("//div[@class='producttab']//div[@id='tab-description']//div[@id='collapse-description']").get()
        results = get_inner_html(html)
        
        print(results.strip())

        print('--- example 2 ---')
        
        html = '<body>hello<span>good</span>world</body>'
        results = get_inner_html(html)
        
        print(results.strip())
```

Comment: thank for your solution @furas. But, there's one problem, sometimes the description did not have tag "p".

I tried to to this
description = response.xpath("div[@class='producttab']//div[@id='tab-description']//div[@id='collapse-description']/text()").get()

but the result is "None"

Comment: you forgot `//`  at the beginning - `xpath("//...")`. If you want HTML then you shouldn't use `/text()` because it gives text without tags. And using single / it gives only text directly after `div` but not from other tags. You would need double // to get all text from all tags - and it needs also `getall()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: hello, @furas. I add update about me trying to get the best solution for it in my question above

Comment: I find out you can use `.re(".+")` to get HTML (more or less) as list `[openning_tag, inner_element, ... , inner_element, closing_tag]` and you would without first and last element and join it `"".join( items[1:-1] )`

Comment: whoa... it's quite tricky than I thought. Not really understand how the regex works to get this solution. anyway, thanks @furas, you save my day :D

Comment: I found it in other question [How to extract raw html from a Scrapy selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887730/how-to-extract-raw-html-from-a-scrapy-selector). But I see possible problem - first element is `<tag>text` and last element is `text</tag>` - in your HMTL these `text` are only `tabs` but in other HTML there can be useful information which are lost in this method. Using `lxml` I would get this text as `.tail`

Comment: old version works because there are `\n` in HTML - but it will not work if HTML will be without `\n`. I created new code which use `lxml` to get inner HTML - it doesn't depend on `\n` and it keep `text` which is between `<opening tag>` and `children`